# Using MS Visual Studio Code, how do I access an MPI library in a Fortran code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran, include, mpi, include-path

I am coding and running a physics simulation in Fortran using MS Visual Studio Code on Windows 11 and I want to use MPI. I have installed Microsoft MPI (MSMPI) and know that it is correctly installed. When I enter 'set msmpi,' into the Windows powershell, I see all directories and locations that I want to be seeing:

```
MSMPI_BENCHMARKS=C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Benchmarks\
MSMPI_BIN=C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\
MSMPI_INC=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include\
MSMPI_LIB32=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x86\
MSMPI_LIB64=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x64\
```

The program itself has the following form (I omit the parts that are irrelevant to the MPI issue):

```
    PROGRAM xyz

    USE MPI

    ...irrelevant...

    INCLUDE 'mpif.h'

     ...irrelevant...

    CALL MPI_INIT(ierr)
    CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)
    CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierr)

    CALL MPI_REDUCE(var1, var2, 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

    ...irrelevant...

    CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

    END PROGRAM xyz
```

When I attempt to run the code, I receive an error message:

> Error: Can't open include file 'mpif.h'`

I have watched several Youtube videos on how to get VS Code to access the MPI library, but I have only been able to gather information piece-meal, because some of these information sources are older, i.e., VS Code no longer contains the settings and options as they're shown in the videos. So far, I have only been able to gather that I must make entries into the settings.JSON file. At the moment, this is what I have:

```
    {
        "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
        "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
        "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
        "fortran.preferredCase": "uppercase",
        "fortran.linter.compiler": "gfortran",
        "editor.renderWhitespace": "none",
        "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
        "editor.tabSize": 6,
        "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
            "C :\\Program Files\\Microsoft MPI\\MPI\\Include",
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",   
        ],

        "fortran.linter.includePaths": [
            "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\MPI\\Include",
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        
        ],
        "fortran.fortls.preprocessor.directories": [
      
        ],
        "jake.autoDetect": "on",
        "grunt.autoDetect": "on",
        "gulp.autoDetect": "on",
        "json.schemas": [
    
        ]
        }
```

I am not sure what I must do from here out. Is this what my settings.JSON file should look like?

I continue to receive an error message that the header file cannot be found when I run the code. I apologize in advance if I am overlooking something that is obvious to a more experienced programmer. I am younger student who is still new to programming and this is the first time that I've ever had to code while manually accessing libraries. Any help at all would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Please tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. See the tag descriptions of tags that you select. The code sample is at least Fortran 90 anyway. If you do `use MPI`, do **not** also use `include 'mpif.h'`. One use one of these, not both.

Comment: ... and what @VladimirFГероямслава might have added ... use `use MPI` rather than `include 'mpif.h'`.  Using the module rather than the include file traps more mistakes at compile time.

Comment: Oh, and you might find you can `use mpi_f08`, though I have my doubts that MS are that up to date.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Thank you. I have tried only using 'use MPI' and I have tried only using 'use mpi_f08.' Neither of these make a difference. I continue to get the same error message: "Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'mpi.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory."

And I am not sure that it makes much of a difference - since the issue is more or less with VS Code - but the format is Fortran-77 (not Fortran-90), i.e., the file is a .f file, not a .f90 file.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is an editor.  Which Fortran compiler are you using (gfortran/ifort etc)?

Comment: @IanH: gfortran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use MS-MPI.

However, mpi.mod is not provided itself: you have to create it by compiling the file mpi.f90 in the MS-MPI include directory. You do this with whichever compiler you are using with VS Code (which appears to be gfortran). Note that you will also need to copy the file mpifptr.h from the .\x64 subdirectory before trying to compile mpi.f90.

I concur that you are probably going to have to run mpiexec from the command line to actually run your executable.

I did summarise my experience of installing the MS-MPI system for ifort (and, as an aside, gfortran) at [Fortran MPI using Cygwin64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75444805/fortran-mpi-using-cygwin64/75449313#75449313) (*ignore the thread title, I was NOT running on Cygwin*). Note that: (a) I was compiling and running from the command line, not a code editor like VS Code; (b) I created separate mpi.mod files for the different compilers: ifort and gfortran; (c) when actually compiling a code using MPI with gfortran some more compiler options need  to be set, as the stringent type checking of the modern Fortran standard doesn't sit entirely happily with the void* pointers implicit in MPI calls.

**EDIT:** Create the following batch file with, e.g., notepad, and call it m.bat, putting it in the same directory as your program file. NOTE: please read to the end of the whole post before running this batch file. The first line should contain the location of the folder where mpi.mod is; if it is elsewhere, then adapt this line. The second line indicates where your MPI libraries are.

```
set OPTC=-I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include\gfortran" -ff2c -fallow-argument-mismatch
set OPTL="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x64\msmpi.lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x64\msmpifec.lib"
call gfortran %OPTC% -o %1.exe %1.f90 %OPTL%
```

Suppose that your program file is called test.f90. Then you can compile and link it by issuing (from the command line, in the same folder as your test.f90 file):

```
m.bat test
```

It should create an executable test.exe, which you can run by issuing the following command (again, from the command line, in the same folder as test.exe), e.g. for 2 processors:

```
mpiexec -n 2 test.exe
```

Obviously, you can substitute "test" by whatever filename (minus any extension) you have given your program file.

NOTE: your compiler appears to be somewhat older than mine, and the compiler option -fallow-argument-mismatch may be neither accepted nor relevant. Try with and without it if so. Newer compilers, which adhere more strictly to the type-checking requirements of the latest Fortran standard, will require it for MPI calls. Fortran has no real equivalent of the void* pointer implicit in the MPI definitions.

Comment: I really appreciate the help and the link. I'm trying to compile mpi.f90 in the include directory. I've copied mpifptr.h. I'm getting errors like this:

"PARAMETER (MPI_FLOAT_INT=z'8c000000')
                                1
Error: Arithmetic overflow converting INTEGER(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1). This check can be disabled with the option '-fno-range-check' mpi.f90:406:33:" 

and this (the only non-'range-check'):

"USE MPI_CONSTANTS, ONLY: MPI_ADDRESS_KIND  

Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'mpi_constants.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory compilation terminated."

Comment: My apologies. I forgot to create an appropriate subdirectory and did so (called 'gfortran' under 'include'). I've tried to compile the file mpi.f90 as instructed under the link you provided using "gfortran -c -fallow-invalid-boz -fno-range-check mpi.f90" in powershell.
However, I got the following error: "gfortran.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-fallow-invalid-boz'; did you mean '-Wno-invalid-pch'?" So, I then tried "gfortran -c -fno-range-check mpi.f90" (without fallow-invalid-boz) and it took it but I'm not seeing mpi.mod or an .exe file appear in the subdirectory.

Comment: @AD203, you won’t see a .exe file, nor should you expect to: you are merely trying to compile the module file mpi.f90 to mpi.mod. Can you try doing this in the standard windows cmd shell, rather than powershell. If it “took it” then it should create that mpi.mod file in the subdirectory where you were trying to compile it. If you simply run gfortran -c mpi.f90 in a windows cmd window what happens?

Comment: Also, I found it necessary to run cmd.exe with Administrator privileges to write anything into that folder. (Right-click any cmd.exe icon and choose "Run as Administrator", at least in Windows 10.) Using cmd.exe navigate to the relevant folder and try ```gfortran -c mpi.f90```. Please report exactly what warnings and error messages it gives.

Comment: I get 6 errors. Five errors are of the same form, only differing by the last digit : PARAMETER (MPI_FLOAT_INT=z'8c00000n') with n = 0,1,2,3,4. Below each of these, it says: "Arithmetic overflow converting INTEGER(8) to INTEGER(4) at (1). This check can be disabled with the option no-range-check.'" 

The last error is marked with USE MPI_CONSTANTS,ONLY:MPI_ADRESS_KIND and below that it explains "Fatal Error: Can't open module file mpi_constants.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory compilation terminated."

Comment: I re-tried using `gfortran -c mpi.f90 -fno-range-check` and now I have the following files in my inlcude/gfortran subdirectory: mpi.f90, mpi.mod, mpi.o, mpi_base.mod, mpi_constants.mod, mpifptr.h. So it seems to have worked. However, it also seems like the system was having issues converting 8-digit integers to 4-digit integers before, and I'm not really sure what the addition of 'fno-range-check' did in detail. Can I assume that the resulting .mod file is okay? How should I proceed? Thank you again very much for all of the help so far.

Comment: You are unlikely to use an MPI type of MPI_FLOAT_INT or similar parameters, so no worries here. The need for -fno-range-check is because usage in a parameter statement is not standard Fortran, although it is widely used as an extension. (Your compiler is also old: I'd guess gfortran 9.4; you will need a different - as my link - if you upgrade to gfortran 12.2). Go ahead and compile your main code. IMPORTANT: ensure that your INCLUDE path contains wherever you decide to put or leave MPI.mod. You may need further compiler options then (depending on compiler version). Remove ```include mpif.h```

Comment: Again, thank you. I have managed to successfully compile the code and no longer have the line `include mpif.h` in the code. Instead, I use `USE MPI` since mpi.mod is in the subdirectory. However, when I then attempt to run the code (using cmd.exe in administrator mode), I get 5 'undefined reference' errors for 'mpi_init', 'mpi_comm_rank', 'mpi_comm_size', 'mpi_reduce' and 'mpi_finalize.' These are called in the code. I went into the header file mpif.h and during a CTRL+F search noticed that these are NOT in the header file. Should I manually add them? Is the header file the place to do so?

Comment: When you say "successfully compile the code" have you actually managed to LINK it as well? That is, actually create a .exe file. It sounds like you haven't. You need to link against the MPI libraries, which for MS-MPI are (with full paths if you need them) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x64\msmpi.lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x64\msmpifec.lib". Do NOT add anything to the headers: you simply haven't linked against the relevant libraries.

Comment: There is an .exe of the code's program in the subdirectory ./include/gfortran, if that is what you mean. Sorry, I did not realize I needed to link libraries. I've tried googling this and I've even stooped as low as asking ChatBotGPT, but I'm not finding the right instructions. How would I link the libraries? Would it be in the code itself, or would this be something I'd need to do in cmd.exe? If in the code, what should I type? I haven't added anything to the headers.

Comment: @AD203, I have edited my post in your thread to include, at the end, a batch file that will compile and link your program. I have indicated where you may need to make amendments, depending on where you choose to put mpi.mod. You run this batch file ... from the command line ... in whichever directory your MPI-calling fortran program happens to be (anywhere you want it on your computer). The batch file is minimalist in terms of compiler options (you can add checking or optimising options later) and contains full paths (again, can be simplified later).

Comment: Thanks again. I created the m.bat file using the correct paths, but had to change the file to .f90 because, even when specifying .f in .bat file (instead of .f90), it couldn't recognize the file format. Upon compiling, it at least displayed in-code errors (had to change 'c' on comment lines to '!' bcs. going from .f to .f90). Now I get the following problem (I will omit parts of file path names to save on characters as the total amount of characters is limited in the comments here):

Comment: .\MPI\Include\gfortran" -ff2c
.\MPI\Lib\x64\msmpi.lib" ".\Lib\x64\msmpifec.lib"

.\MPI\Include\gfortran>call gfortran -I ".\MPI\Include\gfortran" -ff2c -o AnthonyPure.exe AnthonyPure.f90

".\MPI\Lib\x64\msmpi.lib" ".\MPI\Lib\x64\msmpifec.lib"
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: .\MPI\Lib\x64\msmpi.lib(msmpi.dll): Recognised but unhandled machine type (0x8664) in Import Library Format archive
.\MPI\Lib\x64\msmpi.lib: error adding symbols: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Note: ".\" denotes an entire file path.

Comment: You appear to have successfully included the right mod file, compiled your program and then ... got stuck at the link stage. It looks from the "unhandled machine type (0x8664)" as if you are using a 32-bit linker to try to link 64-bit libraries. Your version of mingw looks very old. As a short-term fix you could try changing every "64" in the pathnames in the batch file to "86" (yes, really!, not "32") and seeing if that works. If that doesn't work then you would have to upgrade to minGW64. (Note that you would have to recompile mpi.f90, with the original options, in the latter case.)

Comment: Sorry, I have exams in mathematics and physics and had little time to look at this again. Nevertheless, this is still on my to-do list. After one of my exams on Friday, I will use the weekend to work on this problem more intensely and will then give your suggestion a try. Again, I cannot convey how much I appreciate a stranger trying so hard to help. It is very kind and I am learning a lot as I go. Thank you. I will report any issues / progress once I implement your suggestions.

Comment: I was finally able to sit down between exams and tend to this again. I waited because I was not sure if something might go wrong and require more time and attention. However, merely switching out the "64" for "86" in the batch file was truly all that had to be done. That did the trick! I was able to completely run the simulation code in the .\include\gfortran subdirectory and the out.dat file produced by the simulation contained all of the correct outputs. I cannot thank you enough!

Answer (score 1):

As Ian, Mark and Vladimir have mentioned in the comments there are some inconsistencies in your description of your issue as well as the code you provided, e.g. making use of `include mpif.h` and `use mpi`.
In addition, you need to be specific about what you are doing in VS Code, the extensions you are using, the version of the editor, your compiler version and the MPI library version. There are too many undetermined parameters for us to be able to provide specific help.

Nonetheless, I will try and give you some general guidelines to get started in VS Code.

From your settings I can tell that you are using Modern Fortran for VS Code.
Modern Fortran for VS Code will not be able to compile and run your MPI, for a plethora of reasons. What you can do is set it up so that the linter is able to locate you MPI modules/files e.g. for my Linux workstation

```
{
    "fortran.linter.includePaths": [
        // Location of your mpi_f08.mod file
        "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/fortran/gfortran-mod-15/openmpi"
    ]
}
```

| Without correct `includePaths` | With `includePaths` |
| --- | --- |
| [image: before] | [image: after] |

This will get rid of any Errors that show up in VS Code but you still won't be able to compile and run your program. For that you will still have to compile and run your program from a terminal

```
mpifort main.f90 -o main.out
mpiexec -n 2 main.out
```

#### Output

```
 Hello from process            0
 Hello from process            1
```

As a side note,
I am not sure if MS-MPI will work for you, there are [a few notably better alternatives](https://www.scivision.dev/windows-mpi-msys2/) like Intel's OneApi and MSYS2 which are widely used throughout the Fortran community.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of information. I'm still fairly new to coding, so I sometimes don't notice how many factors could matter. What I'm doing in VS code: coding and running Monte-Carlo simulations at 500 million iterations per simulation. Version of VS Code (1.77). Compiler: gfortran (6.3.0). MPI library (10.1.12498.18). Extensions used in VS Code: Modern Fortran (3.2.0), Code Runner (0.12.0), C/C++ (1.14.5), fortran-ekon (0.01), Fortran Intellisense (0.6.2). And many apologies, but I'm not familiar with the concept of a linter. What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: Install the *pre-release* of `Modern Fortran` and uninstall `Fortran Intellisense`. Not sure if you need `fortran-ekon` either. A [linter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) is a tool used to analyse your code and detect errors without *you* having to compile every time. The red squiggles that you see are from that.