# How can I get MPI module to work with Fortran using Code:Blocks on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, fortran, mpi, codeblocks, fortran90

I have recieved some code from a colleague which is written in Fortan .f90 files, and was used before on Linux. I am trying to get the code to function on Windows 10 using Code::Blocks. The problem is there is an MPI module which is not being found and I can't work out how to add it to the project.

I am not a computer scientist so please bear with me.
I have recieved some code from a colleague which is written in Fortan .f90 files, and was used before on Linux.
I am trying to get this code to work on Windows as I have not used Linux.

I started by installing and configuring codeblocks using this guide (https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-run-a-Fortran-code-in-a-Windows-computer)

Which worked great for simple scripts.

Now, running the main code, I have a problem as there is a MPI module which cannot be found by the software: here is an example of some of the code.

```
module mpi_param
use mpi
implicit none
!
integer :: i_num,nb_proc
integer :: p1, p2,p3
integer :: i_proc, j_proc, k_proc,i_err
integer, dimension(mpi_status_size) :: i_etat
integer, dimension (1:6) :: i_send

!
end module mpi_param
```

Now, I have downloaded the microsoft MPI so I have the folder;

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI
```

and I have also tried with cygwin downloading all the openmpi packages mentioned here;

https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/cygwin/2014-06/msg00410.html

So I have an mpi.mod the file in this directory

```
C:\cygwin64
```

I have added those paths to the build options compiler search directories in codeblocks, but I continue to get the message, when I build;

```
||Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'mpi.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory|
```

I added the mpi.f90 file or mpi.mod file to the project but that didn't work either.

How can I get code:blocks to 'SEE' or 'FIND' or 'USE' the mpi module? (sorry I don't know the correct terminology)

Honestly, I don't really know/understand what I am doing, I am just trying to get the code running at least, but I am completely lost.

Should I give up on this path and try with Linux somehow? Shall I try something instead of Code::Blocks?

Comment: You need to compile the mpi.f90 file that comes with Microsoft MPI with the COMPILER THAT YOU INTEND TO USE (whichever one is being used by Code::Blocks). The resulting mpi.mod file then needs to be in a folder where you expect include files.

Comment: Thanks, I added the mpi.f90 file to my code::blocks project and did a clean then did a clean and then 'compile current file' - but I got the errors; C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include\mpi.f90|544|Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'mpi_constants.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory|

Comment: have a look at what was done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75725750/using-ms-visual-studio-code-how-do-i-access-an-mpi-library-in-a-fortran-code/75882169#75882169 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75444805/fortran-mpi-using-cygwin64/75449313#75449313 (The use of VSCode or Code::blocks is irrelevant; it is your underlying compiler that matters. I personally would use the command line rather than an IDE anyway.)

Comment: I tried to use ifort but it wants me to install Microsoft Visual Studio. All this seems really complicated and involves lots of downloads and different programs. I think perhaps the easiest way is to just try and use a linux virtual machine as that was how the program was originally used.

Comment: please read all those posts CAREFULLY. You don't need need to use ifort: you could use any of several compilers. If you read the posts CAREFULLY you will find that I also gave instructions there for gfortran as well, which I suspect is the compiler that you have on your computer. Fundamentally, the problem is the same for any of the compilers: you have to compile mpi.f90 to create mpi.mod with the compiler that you are going to use. If you read the posts CAREFULLY you will see which files from MS-MPI are necessary for that.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I think this is beyond my level and I have no idea what I am doing. I thought that Code::Blocks was my compiler, and I think I installed gfortran but I can't find it on the command line. I don't know how codeblocks is using it. Anyway I have got it working on a linux virtual machine in the end. There were lots of different f.90 files in the project and it turns out I needed to use a makefile to make a run file to get the code operational.